# Lubuntu boots into tty1, and when mounted, networks connects but does not work

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, mount, lubuntu

So I booted up an old laptop I had with Lubuntu. I had it with Lubuntu 16.04 and I think it broke when I updated it to 17.04 so I just left it there (it's a dual boot with Windows 7), but I thought I'd finally fix it.
I have two problems:
When I start it, Lubuntu boots into tty1 and, I think, read-only mode. I log in and do.

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

This takes me to the graphical interface. Once there, it works correctly, but now there is a problem: even though I connect to my Wi-Fi network (and I know my network works so that's not the problem), and Lubuntu shows it as connected, it still won't connect to anything, so I can't update nor upgrade packages nor enter the web nor anything. The other problem is that once I shut it down and turn it on again, it will boot to tty again. I'd like to be able to have it boot normally into graphical interface and also to fix the network problem. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 or the 2017-April release is EOL (*end-of-life*). https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/01/17/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-reached-end-of-life-on-january-13-2018/   Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note it's no longer supported on this site due to EOL status (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Question also asked at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462845

Comment: As already answered at UF; your upgrade options are gone (17.04 upgraded to 17.10, then to 18.04 which being the last LXDE supported release. requires re-install to move to later releases) so re-install is your easiest & only on-topic fix here; either Lubuntu 20.04 LTS or Lubuntu 21.04